# Read/Write Local JSON file using Python File executed by GitHub Actions Workflow

Tags: python, json, github

I have a python script that reads in a json file and outputs an updated json file under the same name.

This script executes when running on my local machine, but when the script is executed by GitHub Actions Workflow file it 
(1) can not load the file 
(2) Does not error when writing the file but there is no outputted file to be found

```
import json

# get file
existing_file = json.load(open('example.json'))

# write file
with open('example.json', 'w') as outfile:
  outfile.write(json.dumps({}))
```

The json file is in the same location as the executed file, and I have checked all possible path to see if the file is being written to another location.

Has anyone encountered figured out how to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

Is your json version-controlled? if its not, and because github workers are ephemeral, initially the json won't exist, meaning you should be getting a filenotfounderror. If this is the case, just protect against it:

```py
import json

# get file
try:
    existing_file = json.load(open('example.json'))
except FileNotFoundError:
    existing_file = {}  # TODO or [], depending on the data

# TODO: do something with existing_file
existing_file["foo"] = "bar"  # or existing_file.append("foo"), depending on the data
# write file
with open('example.json', 'w') as outfile:
  outfile.write(json.dumps(existing_file))
```

After that, you have to do something in the github workflow to persist or send the resulting file somewhere, eg by either printing it to console or [exporting it as an artifact](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts).

Comment: Not version controlled, just an existing json file. I have very similar code to your example in my script already. So loading that file is part 1 of my conundrum, and part 2 is successfully saving the file into the local repository

Comment: where does the "existing json file" live? if it exists locally on your computer and its not version controlled, how do you expect the github actions worker to find it? Also, supposing that problem is solved, how would you send it back to the local repo!? Is adding the json to git a valid option? in that case, you could just commit it back in the same or a new branch...

Comment: file lives within the same repo as the script. It sounds like you're saying I must pull/push the file within the actions workflow file

Comment: (1) To get the git-managed files, you should use the github.com/actions/checkout stage, if you're not already using it. (2) Becasue your json file is not git-managed, you need a way to "get" the file from your local repo to the remote github server where your action is running from. for example, upload it to a service like pastebin or whatever. (3) as your json is not git managed, when the workflow is done updating the file, you need a way to recover the updated file from the github server where the action is running from: export artifacts or pastebin, etc...

Comment: Is a github-hosted json not git-managed?

Comment: what do you mean with github-hosted json?  What's github hosted (probably and by default) is the server where your actions are run.